# How to call method on a child React.Component from a parent React.FunctionalComponent?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I call a method on a child component from a parent component? I'm not sure it matters but my parent component is a functional component and the child is a class component. I'm hoping that the switch to function components doesn't mean that all class-based components need to be upgraded?

The parent component looks like this:

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
    const grid = useRef();
    const buttonClick = () => {
        // I want to be able to call a method on <MyGrid> here to
        // tell it to reload the grid (for example)
        grid.current!.reconfigure();
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <JqxButton onClick={buttonClick}>Refresh Grid</JqxButton>
            <MyGrid ref={grid} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

This actually works, though not without errors (which don't seem to crash the app in code sandbox, but it won't compile in VS Code offline). The 'ref' property on MyGrid shows this error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: MyGrid | null) => void) | RefObject<MyGrid> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<MyGrid>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MyGrid | null'.ts(2322)
```

My call to grid.current!.reconfigure() results in this error:

```
Property 'reconfigure' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

I've created a code sandbox with the full setup of the parent and child components here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fc-call-child-component-14rr3

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Typescript but I do have some C# experience (so I can understand enough to get myself into trouble) -- take this with a grain of salt as I'm unsure if this is best practices, etc... but it appears assigning the type of `any` causes the errors to disappear. `const grid = useRef<any>();` Just throwing it out there... EDIT: at a high level though, you should prob create a boolean property on the table component which you can set from any parent - if its true, run the 'refresh' method on the table... The ref thing feels hacky to me.

Comment: Thank you. That worked (at least code sandbox isn't complaining anymore). I ended up moving the buttons into the MyGrid component so that I had internal access to the grid and I'm refreshing it that way now. But it's good to know that good old 'any' comes to the rescue here. I swear, TypeScript is a blessing and a curse sometimes.